# Wireless problem: Once turned off won't turn on, does not show wlan0

Tags: wireless

I am a linux newbie. I attended a linux intro. workshop and I faced this problem during the workshop even organisers were not able to solve them so I am posting it here:

When I run `ifconfig` command on my laptop it doesn't show any wireless extensions such as wlan0 --even if I am connected to wireless-- so I tried `iwconfig` and it said "no wireless extensions."

But both wifi and bluetooth are working properly. Just there is one problem. Sometimes if I switch OFF wireless(from ubuntu or windows) then ubuntu is not able to switch it ON I have to boot into windows and then start it from there(this does not happen always)!
Is there anything seriously wrong with my laptop?

Info about my laptop:

```
HP Pavillion dv6
Intel i7, RAM 8GB triple booted with Lubuntu, Ubuntu and Windows
```

I am running 32 bit Ubuntu

Thanks in advance!

Comment: thanks for editing it properly,This is my first question on Ask ubuntu so ... :)

Comment: How exactly are you switching it off? Do you use a mechanic switch, a special key or do you do it via the software switch on the ubuntu desktop?

Comment: Also, there is nothing wrong with your laptop, it is just different ;) .

Comment: When it's turned off and you can't turn it on, does it help to do? sudo rfkill unblock all

Comment: I use the software switch on the ubuntu desktop. Thanks!

Comment: I will try using rfkill next time

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with Lenovo Ideapad S10.
On the terminal:

```
rfkill list
```

It showed two devices:

> `0:ideapad_wlan:Wireless LAN`
>   `Softblock: no`
>   `Hardblock: yes`
>
> `1:brcmwL-0 Wireless Lan`  ( I think it is Broadcom WLAN)
>   `softblock:no`
>   `hardblock:yes`

I checked the Bios wireless switch it was ON

Then I did:

```
rfkill unblock 0
rfkill unblock 1
```

This fixes the problem, which is strange because it was a hardblock, but it works.